# SQL: what is the fastest query to find which record is related to a given record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table structure

```
Table A
-------
id , name
1  , A1
2  , A2
3  , A3
4  , A4
5  , A5
6  , A6

Table B
-------
id , name , tableA_id
1  , B1   , 1
2  , B2   , 2
....

Table C
-------
id , name , tableA_id
1  , C1   , 3
2  , C2   , 4
....

Table D
-------
id , name , tableA_id
1  , C1   , 5
2  , C2   , 6
....
```

**Questions**

- if i was given Table A id: 3 what is the fastest way to find the
  related row from B,C,D tables?
- i will be running this a lot will this be okay?
- how can i make sure that for each record in table A there will be only 1 and only 1 record either in B,C,D
- is there anything i can do to improve the structure so i can achieve what i'm looking for using a faster query? i was thinking of 2 solutions but i'm not sure if it would be a good practice

Solution1 :

```
Table A
-------
id , name , B_id, C_id, D_id
1  , A1   ,  1  ,     ,
2  , A2   ,  2  ,     ,
3  , A3   ,     ,  1  ,
4  , A4   ,     ,  2  ,
5  , A5   ,     ,     , 1
6  , A6   ,     ,     , 2
```

Solution2 :

```
Table A
-------
id , name , table, id
1  , A1   ,  B  ,  1
2  , A2   ,  B  ,  2
3  , A3   ,  C  ,  1
4  , A4   ,  C  ,  2
5  , A5   ,  D  ,  1 
6  , A6   ,  D  ,  2
```

But i'm not comfortable with both solutions since i don't think i can apply restrictions / map it as a proper foreign keys

Comment: for what purpose you are using tables B,C,D ? let me know plz,, i think there is no need , a single table can be enough because you are storing same data in all three tables

Comment: @uvais everything has a purpose, otherwise there will be no B,C,D

Comment: ok then you can use outer join

Comment: and what exactly you want , plz draw the same

Comment: While I don't know about putting everything in the same table, knowing what you _are_ using the system for is a good idea.  Beyond that, trying to get a 'unique' linked row will be difficult with your current design; I believe most/all RDBMSs would require triggers, and you'd essentially have to lock the tables (and risk deadlock) to make it work.  Your other solutions solve this initial problem, but I don't like them much either; can we get more information please?  This is _potentially_ a table-inheritance problem, but I don't think MySQL supports that feature.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse what i'm trying to achieve is that i have 3 different labels i'm selling in my website take it as (furniture, cars, houses) each one of them has its own properties and way-to-use. they share some columns as of (title,desc .. etc) but each one of them has 10+ unique columns. but on the order/ cart / other levels they are all treated as product. i'm trying to find a way to link all of them, so in the cart/order i can deal with a product_id which i don't care if it's a car or a house rather than creating an order table -for example- for each one of them. i'm using MySQL btw.

Comment: @uvais i described what i'm trying to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a different option, especially if you're going to be selling more than three item categories in the future.
Roughly speaking, you need 4 tables (before any for languages/localization):

```
Product_Category
----------------
id  -- autoincrement id
name  --  varchar

Product
----------
id  -- autoincrement id
productCategoryId  -- fk referenct to Product_Category.id
name  -- varchar
price  -- decimal/numeric
(other columns as needed)

Attribute
------------
id  -- autoincrement id
name  -- varchar
type  -- code
description  -- varchar

Product_Attribute
-------------------
productId  -- fk reference to Product.id
attributeId -- fk reference to Attribute.id
value  -- varchar
```

(yes, as much as I loathe EAV setups in general, this is the kind of case it was made for)

Why do things like this?  Well, in general it's not great to add a new table every time you add a new product type.  In fact, you want to put as many attributes as possible inside `Product` itself - this will need to be a balancing act - try to figure out what some commonly queried attributes are and put them in that table, *even if not every category has them* (obviously, this would require nullable columns).
Additionally, some `Product` columns should potentially pull 'double duty' (...sort of...) here; cars obviously have color, as does furniture - it's just one is paint and the other stain.
Everything else goes into `Product_Attribute`.  Note the use of `Attribute` to help keep things like misspellings of attributes and duplicate entries down (and it should be something your product-entry team curates, not customers).  Although, you might be surprised what a good index and search function over your titles/descriptions can produce.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i just have a question, roughly how many columns / records the `Product` table might hold on for without affecting performance?

Comment: I don't know what MySQL tops out at (please consult your documentation, but you usually run into a 'good design' limit for column count long before you hit the actual DB limit.  For row count, that's going to be based on what hardware you're using, and what you mean by 'performance' - most modern RDBMSs store anything under 1000 rows completely in memory.  At minimum, you're going to want a good set of indices.  Assuming decent 'server' hardware, you likely won't have any real problems until after 1 mil rows in a table...

Answer (score 1):

If a record in Table A is related to one or more records to Table B or C or D, then your design is good. However you could probably merge the B, C and D tables into one and add only one to differentiate it like for example CategoryType. Let's say we name our merge Table as M. The structure would probably like this.

```
ID, Name, CategoryType, tableA_id
```

With sample Data:

```
ID  Name  CategoryType tableA_id
1   C1     C             1
2   B1     B             2
3   A1     A             3
```

However if a record in Table A is related to one and only one record in either Table B or C or D then it should be in one table.

On the other hand using your current DB structure you could probably use `UNION ALL` to merge results and `LIMIT 1` to make sure only one match shows up, like:

```
SELECT a.id, b.name as OneName
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableB B
ON a.id = b.tableA_id
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, b.name as OneName
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableC C 
ON a.id = c.tableA_id
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id, b.name as OneName
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN tableC D 
ON a.id = d.tableA_id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I totally understand but each B,C,D tables has 10+ unique columns so merging them doesn't seems a good idea for the long run, i keep the shared columns in table A and unique columns for each of them in it's own table.

Comment: If that's the case then both your solutions 1 and 2 that you've shown would not be a good solution as well. So, which means you stick with your current db structure and you could probably use UNION ALL (for all common fields) and then LIMIT 1 to make sure only one match to either Table B, C or D is included.